# Is there a way to get the last error in php4

Tags: error-handling, php4

PHP 5 has error_get_last. Is there any way to completely or at least partially replicate the same functionality in PHP4.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ripped from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php#103539) (courtesy of php at joert dot net):

```
<?php
if( !function_exists('error_get_last') ) {
    set_error_handler(
        create_function(
            '$errno,$errstr,$errfile,$errline,$errcontext',
            '
                global $__error_get_last_retval__;
                $__error_get_last_retval__ = array(
                    \'type\'        => $errno,
                    \'message\'        => $errstr,
                    \'file\'        => $errfile,
                    \'line\'        => $errline
                );
                return false;
            '
        )
    );

    function error_get_last() {
        global $__error_get_last_retval__;
        if( !isset($__error_get_last_retval__) ) {
            return null;
        }
        return $__error_get_last_retval__;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Also interesting to learn about create_function from the answer. Looks kind of nasty.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you will have to do some programming, you need to attach error handler

```
$er_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

but before this you need to write your "myErrorHandler"

```
function myErrorHandler($errNumber, $errString, $errFile, $errLine)
{
  /*now add it to session so you can access it from anywhere, or if you have class with the static variable you can save it there */

 $_SESSION["Error.LastError"] = $errNumber . '<br>' . $errString . '<br>' . $errFile . '<br>' . $errLine;
  }
```

Now when error is occured you can get it by

```
if(isset($_SESSION["Error.LastError"]))
  $str = $_SESSION["Error.LastError"];
```

now to replicate your method you need to create function

```
function get_last_error()
{
$str = "";
if(isset($_SESSION["Error.LastError"]))
      $str = $_SESSION["Error.LastError"];
return $str;
}
```

Comment: +1, I like the idea, but I don't think `error_get_last` persists between sessions (it's just within the context of the currently executing environment). Probably better just to store it in a global variable or something.

Comment: error_get_last doesn't exist in php 4.3.xx but this is the way to keep your last error while session exists.

Comment: I'm saying that the REAL `error_get_last` only applies to the current script. It doesn't last from one connection to the next.

Comment: jap, u are correct, but you can always set after session_start(); unset of Error.LastError so it will be valid only for same request.

Comment: See my answer, notice it's just using global variables.

Comment: global variables should be avoided in programming

Comment: not when they're appropriate. Besides, what on earth do you think `$_SESSION` is? Practice what you preach there, buddy.